# Jenkins GAE Deploy hangs on Getting current resource limits

Tags: django, google-app-engine, jenkins

I am deploying a django project to GAE. When I deploy locally everything runs as smooth as silk, however when I try to deploy from Jenkins it gets hung on the following line:

```
12:42 PM Getting current resource limits.
```

**Full Deploy Log**

```
12:42 PM Application: <gaeproject>; version: dev (was: 1)
12:42 PM Host: appengine.google.com
12:42 PM Starting update of app: <gaeproject>, version: dev
12:42 PM Getting current resource limits.
```

**Deploy Command**

```
python $GAE_PATH/appcfg.py -A $GAE_INSTANCE -V $GAE_VERSION update .
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue before? What might be causing this hang?